# 503 Error Area Code Is Not Set

Tags: magento2, frontend-error

I am getting a 503 Error randomly on my site with "Area Code is Not Set" I have not been able to track it down as it appears to be at random. The only way I can consistently get it to happen is to open 10-20 links at the same time, at least one of those pages will have the error.

The stack trace is not the same as far as I can tell between when the error is thrown that would narrow it down to an extension. Error Log [here](https://pastebin.com/qELtANtF) and [here](https://pastebin.com/YVFfTEuV).

Also running "php bin/magento config:show" returns an area code not set error, none of the other CLI commands seem to do that though.

ENV: PHP 7.0.32, Nginx 1.10.2, Magento 2.2.5

Comment: Do you use any third party module? Maybe MSP_DevTools?

Comment: I do have quite a few 3rd party modules. I have thought about disabling them one by one until I find the issue, I was hoping there would be a better way, or if anyone else has had this issue.

Comment: I found similar issue but it was related with third party module that was using set Area in construct function, thats why we need to find what module cause this

Comment: Are you using magento enterprise with the staging module? I am seeing these exact same traces and am currently debugging.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this issue can be resolved by increasing your redis `max_concurrency` value in `app/etc/env.php`, try stepping it above what you have now a little. Don't use `999999` ;)

```
'session' =>
    array(
        'save' => 'redis',
        'redis' =>
            array(
                'max_concurrency' => '999999',
```

I have raised an issue with Magento (https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19207) as I was seeing the same thing as you on 2.1.15 EE.

The issue is hard to understand as the error handling for a redis `ConcurrentConnectionsExceededException` is incorrect.

```
public function read($sessionId)
{
    try {
        return parent::read($sessionId);
    } catch (ConcurrentConnectionsExceededException $e) {
        require $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::PUB)->getAbsolutePath('errors/503.php');
    }
}
```

By simply requiring the `errors/503.php` page it triggers some error handling which launches a new `ObjectManager` with an entirely new `State` config which is missing the area information. However there is no `exit` command issued anywhere so the rest of the request processes as normal, meaning you see this garbled `Area code is not set` error.

Essentially the system tried to throw one error, messed it up, and threw another error instead.

I believe you will be able to resolve this on your system by fixing the initial `ConcurrentConnectionsExceededException` error.

Comment: I upped the max_concurrency to 10 from 6 and that seems to have curbed the issue a bit although still happening, I have not tried your fix in the github issue yet, but looks to be promising.

Comment: The change in the github issue will only report the error correctly. if it's still occurring maybe try increasing further, see how your system handles with 15, 20, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I changed the value from 12 to 20 for max_concurrency. It solved the issue.